# Make my call synchronous

Tags: angularjs, loops, asynchronous

The problem here is that the call inside the loop is not always finishing before the next one begins. For example, sometimes the loop finishes first. Basically i need this to be asynchronous. The second loop should not begin until the first loop has finished.

The loop in my controller is like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.myArr.length; i++) {
     $scope.input1 = $(".input" + i).val();
     $scope.input2 = $(".input" + i).val();

     myService.addValues($scope.input1, $scope.input2);
}
```

Which sends the values to the service:

```
var addValues = function (name, sets, reps) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "URL",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
            value1: value1,
            value2: value2
        }
    }).success(function () {
        console.log("Values added");
    });
};
```

Note that i need the loop function to be in the controller so it can get the values from the view, while the http request being in my service which is located on another JS file.

Examples are appreciated!

Comment: you're doing ajax requests, which means asynchronous. if you want ordered results, then use synchronous requests, or wait until ALL your requests are done before processing the results.

Comment: What is the point of the loop? You're not referencing `i` or elements from `$scope.myArr` at all...

Answer (score 1):

Look into using the `$q.all` method to resolve an array of promises in a predictable manner.

http://www.martin-brennan.com/using-q-all-to-resolve-multiple-promises/

```
var promises = [promiseAlpha(), promiseBeta(), promiseGamma()];

$q.all(promises).then((values) => {
    console.log(values[0]); // value alpha
    console.log(values[1]); // value beta
    console.log(values[2]); // value gamma
});
```

In your application, you might do something like the following:

```
var allPromises = [];

for(var i = 0; i < $scope.myArr.length; i++) {
     $scope.input1 = $(".inputA"+ i).val();
     $scope.input2 = $(".inputB" + i).val();

     allPromises.push(myService.addValues($scope.input1, $scope.input2));
}

// remember to inject $q service into controller/factory
$q.all(allPromises).then(function(values){
    console.log(values); // array of values in order they were added
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have been looking into it a bit. However i'm not sure how to apply it on my case

Comment: Added a more thorough example.

Comment: I can see this working if was a GET request, but since it's a POST, the data is getting posted (in the wrong order) the same time it's pushed to "allPromises"

Comment: Ohhh, so you need the first promise to resolve before you even initiate the second post? That is somewhat different...

Comment: Yes, they're supposed to make the POST requests in the same order as the loop. Right now they get posted to the database in an asynchronous manner/random order. Is there any solution to this?